# Use randint and a limited number of Python tools to make the random numbers different and shuffle up a string

Tags: python

I'm learning Python from Brian Heinold's A Practical Introduction to Python Programming where one of the exercises in the Strings chapter reads as follows

> An anagram of a word is a word that is created by rearranging the
> letters of the original.
> For instance, two anagrams of idle are deli and lied. Finding anagrams that are real words is beyond our reach until Chapter 12.
> Instead, write a program that asks the user for a string and returns a
> random anagram of the string—in other words, a random rearrangement of
> the letters of that string.

The trick is we have not covered def and while yet, and the shuffle function has not been mentioned, which means we may not use it.
I have written a code which does the job except it often generates idential random numbers which is why the string does not get scrambled the way it is supposed to, e.g. if I punch in abc, I might get ccc or bba or aaa. Please advise how can I modify my code to make the random numbers different from one another? Thank you. Here is my code:

```
s = ''
string = input('Enter a word: ')
from random import randint

for i in range(len(string)):
    randindex = randint(0,(len(string)-1))
    #a = randindex
    s = s + string[randindex]
    #a += 1
    # I tried to play with this additional variable.
    # I wanted to write s = s + string[a] instead if the line
    # that comes in between the comments.
    # It did not work. Probably I need an individual cycle for that...
    # I'm sure missing something.
print(s)
```

Comment: One solution: after picking a random character, remove it from string, so that it is one shorter each time around the loop. Another solution is to generate two random indices and swap those two characters (shuffle), and repeat enough times so the string is sufficiently randomized.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot use *random* module at all? (but you are using it here?)

Comment: @craigb, thank you. I'll try to apply that.

Comment: @DanielHao, normally the author's exercises require only the stuff that was mentioned in the theory part. The random module wasn mentioned previously but shuffle was not.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very efficient, but it is uniformly random, and for shortish words the inefficiency doesn't matter. Maybe it gives you an idea about how to do it better.

The idea is that we accumulate a new word (the anagram) by placing each letter in sequence at a random place in the new word. Python strings are immutable -- I'm sure your text covered that fact -- so in order to insert a letter, we need to make a new string consisting of the part before the random split point, the new letter, and then the part after the split point. We do that for each letter in the original, which is why this solution isn't very efficient.

```py
from random import randint

word = input('Enter a word: ')
anagram = ''
for letter in word:
    position = randint(0, len(anagram))
    before = anagram[:position]
    after = anagram[position:]
    anagram = before + letter + after
print(anagram)
```

Comment: that definitely is one way to do it. Thank you.